# PHP - Read Digital Signature of an Executable and verify Author, How can I validate digital signatures of an Executable using PHP

Tags: php

We have a few Executables files (Installer) uploaded to our web server.
Those installers are digitally signed - Microsoft Authenticode, with SHA1 and SHA256. Standard binary code signing - from Desktop.

We upload this installer to our web server.

We want to verify the installer before it is served to end users.
This is a verification process where we want to verify if the executable/installer is tempered. If so, the executable will not have our digital signature and thus we do not want our end users to download it.

I already tried openssl_get_publickey and openssl_verif but no luck.
When I use certificate.pem & sign-ID.bin on Windows OS with OpenSSL I am able to verify the installer digital signature.

It is not mandatory for me to use openssl_verif, if there are any ways to verify the file's property and check for the author in the digital signatures, I will be able to compare the author name with the expected value.

Following is the php code I am using.

```
// fetch certificate from file and ready it
$fp = fopen("/mypath/certificate.pem", "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);

$pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);

$fp = fopen("/mypath/sign-ID.bin", "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);

$signature = $cert;


$fp = fopen($path, "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
$datapath=$cert;

// state whether signature is okay or not
// use the certificate, not the public key
//$ok = openssl_verify($datapath, $signature, $pubkeyid,  OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256); tried both sha 256 and sha1
$ok = openssl_verify($datapath, $signature, $pubkeyid,  OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);


$error = "";

while ($msg = openssl_error_string() !== false) {
    $error .= $msg.'<br />';
}

if (!empty($error)) {
    echo $error; // 1
}

if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you have the SHA1/SHA256 hash and want to see if the file matches this hash.

There are command line tools you can use for this. You could use `exec()` or something like that and then compare the output with the hash you have:

```
$actualHash = exec(sprintf("sha1sum %s", $filename));
if ($expectedHash !== trim($actualHash)) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Obviously this relies that `sha1sum` is installed on your server and that the output generated is only the hash. If there is some disclaimer, like for example the Microsoft Integrity Check Tool outputs (if I remember correctly) you might have to extract the `$actualHash` from the exec-output first.

Another way of comparing the hash of the content is to read the file in and then pass the string to php's hash function.

```
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$actualHash = sha1($content);
// ... Do comparison
```

This could be irky with encoding, but should theoretically result in the same output. If you are asking for preference, I would rather take the output from a proven tool, then use the latter method.